# Recommended approach to paginate 200 stored procedures using on ASP.NET MVC and SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures, pagination, sql-server-2014

I'm developing a website with multiple reports with a wide variety of records, from a few ones to thousands.

These reports are written in stored procedures. To avoid adding `@pagenumber`, `@pagecount`, `@columfilter`, `@columorder`, etc... to the stored procedures  and because I'm receiving the data to the web via JSON, this is what I'm doing:

1. The user request via AJAX the first page of a report
2. The webserver executes the stored procedure
3. The webserver copy the result to a MongoDB collection
4. The webserver return the MongoDB collection taking in account page, pagelength, column filters, orders, etc
5. In the following requests I get the data from MongoDB directly very fast

The approach work very well with small set of data rows, but with thousands of rows the step 2 and 3 begins to delay.

Any idea how to improve the pagination/ordering/filtering trying to not interfere with the queries inside each SP? Exist a way to do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The first question I would have is why use MongoDB to store results rather than store globally in memory in asp.net?

Second question is if results are cached (e.g. in MongoDB) how long before they become stale and you want to refresh/requery them?

I don't know all the details of your setup but the short answer is that your overhead seems to be in the query and/or in returning the (full) results back to the application.  The only way to overcome this is to make your query(s) more efficient or to reduce the data sent back (network speed could be an issue if there is a LOT of results).  And the simplest way to do this is to do the hard work and add pagination to your stored procedures.

So...

1) Consider if you can use in memory caching of results, it may help with steps 3 & 4.

2) Time your queries and see if the issue is how long the query takes or if it is that it is returning a lot of data.  If it's a slow query can you make the query faster (optimise, add indexes, etc), if it's a lot of data you probably want paging (altho removing columns can help here).

3) Maybe it is just a few of your stored procedures that have lots of results or are slow.  Can you add paging to these and not the others?

4) If these don't help you'll probably have to do the hard work and add paging to the stored procedures.

Comment: Thank you for you time, I didn't know I can do memory caching with ASP.NET, I'm going to read about that. The results are cached until refresh the page, or after 2hs Mongo remove it automatically by expiration. The site have few users, is a datawarehouse site for an enterprice.